# Python to interactively choose a range of cells in Excel

Tags: python, excel

From a Python application, I want the user to choose an excel file, have the file open up on screen and then have the user highlight a range of interest in a worksheet then read the data in that range back into Python for some manipulation.  So something like:

```
workdir = cwd()
ftypes = [['*.xls', '*.xlsx','*.xlsm', '*.xlsb', 'Excel Workbook files']]
filename = fileopenbox(msg = None, title = 'Workbook with Data', default = workdir, filetypes = ftypes, multiple = False)    
if filename is None:
        return
os.system('start EXCEL.EXE' + filename)
workbook = excel.load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
sheet = workbook.active
cell_range = sheet['A1':'D29','E1':'F29'] # want this to be chosen interactively by the user on the screen
cell_vals=cell_range.values
cell_values = np.asarray(cell_values, dtype = np.float32)
#continue doing something with the data.
```

I have looked for a while but cannot find the answer so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t know if it’s possible, but I think the best area to look for a solution would be in excel macros. Since these are written in vba, you should be able to pipe it’s output to a file that can be read by your Python program. Sorry I can’t help more, but I don’t know much about how they work.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  That is what I was afraid of.  Hmm.  The Excel files are coming directly from our analytical department with test data.  Unfortunately the data can be on multiple worksheets and multiple ranges.  They have been unable (or unwilling) to standardize, so I was hoping I can streamline this by having everything done in a python app.  Do you know of any platform that may be able to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: I have never heard of such a program so I think the only way to do this would be to do it yourself. I don't have excel myself so I can't really help you much further, but if you want to give it a go in VBA I'll point you to [selection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa223084(v=office.11)) and [writing files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198715(v=technet.10)). Looking at these docs, it certainly look possible, even though VBA is pretty awful, so if you do decide to try it, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to get hold of an old excel version so I thought I would properly answer this question since it's really interesting. After fighting with VBA for quite a while, I managed to come to this code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:/test/TestFile.txt")
    
    Dim rs As Long
    Dim cs As Long
    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Selection
    rs = Selection.Rows.Count
    cs = selRange.Columns.Count
    
    For i = 1 To rs
        For j = 1 To cs
            oFile.Write (selRange.Cells(i, j) & ",")

        Next j
        oFile.WriteBlankLines (1)
    Next i
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Essentially, this code:

- Defines and creates a file system Object
- Defines and creates a text file object
- Defines rows, columns and selectionRange variables
- Sets the variables from Excel's Selection object
- Loops through the rows and columns to write to the file in a csv format
- Closes the file and cleans up

VBA is a nightmare so I would suggest doing the rest of your data handling in python. I had trouble starting a python script at the end of a file, but if you want that then use something like `Shell "C:/test/main.bat"` and the make a `main.bat` file and put `start C:/test/main.pyw` in it, which is convoluted but seems to work fine (I used pyw since it runs the program without the console, you don't have to do that). Hopefully this helps, comment if you have any questions.